# Group by random column in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need something like this in MS ACCESS SQL

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    col1, 
    col2, 
    random(col3) 
FROM 
    table
GROUP BY
    ID, 
    col1, 
    col2
```

NOTE:

I want to remove duplicates choosing random value of col3.

INPUT:

```
+----+------+------+------+
| Id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
| 1  | A    | B    | 7    |
+----+------+------+------+
| 1  | A    | B    | 10   |
+----+------+------+------+
```

RESULT:

```
+----+------+------+------+
| Id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
| 1  | A    | B    | 7    |
+----+------+------+------+
```

REQUERY:

```
+----+------+------+------+
| Id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
| 1  | A    | B    | 10   |
+----+------+------+------+
```

Comment: A random column from the table or a predefined column that grabs a random value?

Comment: I need remove duplicates but choose random row, id, col1, col2 are same but col3 not same

Comment: As you use `random()` like an aggregation function, I wonder if you want a random value from `col3` in the group?

Comment: I need something like an aggregation function but not MIN or MAX, I need random of col3

Comment: Random function MAY return the same col3 values on subsequent requery iterations.  Especially with above data where only two values of col3 exist.  If REQUERY has a requirement to cycle thru each of the col3 values before repeating then we have a different problem.

Comment: Do you have a unique, not null column (or a primary key) in your table?

Comment: @stickybit, No, I don't have primary key in my table.

Comment: @donPablo, Yes, it may return the same col3 and not problem with that.